# What is the opposite of an inline formula?

Tags: inline

What is the technical term to refer to a "regular" equation in the center of a page in latex?

I know that a formula in the middle of a sentence is called "inline"

Would it be called an "outline" formula?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "technical term" you mean "TeXnical term" `:-)` the phrase you are looking for is *display math*. From the TeXbook, p. 85

> Just as people get into different moods, `TeX` gets into different “modes.” (Except
> that `TeX` is more predictable than people.) There are six modes:
>
> - Vertical mode. [Building the main vertical list, from which the pages of
>   output are derived.]
> - Internal vertical mode. [Building a vertical list for a vbox.]
> - Horizontal mode. [Building a horizontal list for a paragraph.]
> - Restricted horizontal mode. [Building a horizontal list for an hbox.]
> - Math mode. [Building a mathematical formula to be placed in a horizontal list.]
> - Display math mode. [Building a mathematical formula to be placed on
>   a line by itself, temporarily interrupting the current paragraph.]